# Access to stored properties of a struct from a extension in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a Stack struct in `Swift` and making it comply to `Generator` and `Sequence`.

```
class Stack<T> {
    var items:Array<T>

    var depth : Int{ return items.count}



    init(){
        items = Array<T>()
    }

    func push(elm:T){
        items += elm
    }

    func pop()->T?{
        if depth > 0{
            return items.removeLast()
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I get into trouble when trying to make it comply to `Generator`. I tried adding a nested type through an extension, that's when I get an error:

```
extension Stack{

    struct StackGenerator: Generator{

        var current = 0
        mutating func next() -> T?{
            let rc = items[current] // Get an error here: can't access items in Stack

        }
    }
}
```

The compiler won't let me access the `Stack.items` property form within `StackGenerator`. Is this to be expected? How can I work around this?

Comment: With Xcode 6 GM, you have to replace `items += elm` with: `items += [elm]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic types can't have nested types - you need to either build `StackGenerator` outside of your `Stack` declaration, or use the `GeneratorOf<T>` type in your `generate` function.

The first option could look like this:

```
class Stack<T> : SequenceType {
    var items: Array<T>
    var depth: Int { return items.count }

    init(){
        items = Array<T>()
    }

    func push(elm:T){
        items += [elm]
    }

    func pop()->T?{
        if depth > 0 {
            return items.removeLast()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func generate() -> StackGenerator<T> {
        return StackGenerator(stack: self)
    }
}

struct StackGenerator<T>: GeneratorType {
    typealias Element = T
    var current = 0
    var stack: Stack<T>

    init (stack: Stack<T>) {
        self.stack = stack
    }

    mutating func next() -> T? {
        if current < self.stack.items.count {
            return self.stack.items[current++] // Get an error here: can't access items in Stack
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that sucks... I mean, not being able to define nested types in generic types. I hope they fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Wait a minute, this doesn't work either, and it's not a generic type:

class A  {
    
    var name = "Fred"
    class B {
        func foo()->String{
            return name + " Flinstone"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Right, that's not how nested types work. It seems like you're trying to treat a [nested type](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html) as if it were a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).